# VSCode persist search preferences

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to configure my settings so that every time I reopen VSCode editor I do not lose search preferences (ie. Match Case, Use Regular Expression etc). For example in my last search if I activate **Match Case** how do I make this setting available even after reloading VSCode?

I was looking [VSCode customization section](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace) but not found any clue on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the VSCode team. As of VSCode 1.8 this is not supported, but we have a feature request tracking this work: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11574